# nested ng-repeat showing wrong $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, nested-loops

i tried working with ng-repeat but got stucked when `$index` keeps showing the wrong thing
here is my code
http://codepen.io/netwrkx/pen/VamRjo

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="row responsive-sm " ng-repeat="items in DataAPI">
        <div class="card1" ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="">            
                    <input type="submit" ng-click="showFullPost($index)"></input>
                    <h4 class="post-title">{{item}} {{$index}}</h4>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.items = ["orange", "mango", "grape", "apple", "pineapple", "lemon"];

    $scope.DataAPI =  [["orange", "mango"],["grape", "apple"], [ "pineapple", "lemon"]];

    $scope.showFullPost = function(index){
                    console.log($scope.items[index] );
                    //$state.go('post');
                }

}
```

trying to loop through

child `$scope.items = ["orange", "mango", "grape", "apple", "pineapple", "lemon"];`

parent  `$scope.DataAPI =  [["orange", "mango"],["grape", "apple"], [ "pineapple", "lemon"]];`

`$index` keeps showing only orange and mango. what am i missing??

ANY IDEA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will label the items 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

```
<div ng-repeat="items in DataAPI track by $index">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="idx = $parent.$index * items.length + $index">
    <button ng-click="showFullPost(idx)">View Full</button>
    <h4 class="post-title">{{item}} {{idx}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner `ng-repeat` creates a new scope in which the inner `$index` is populated and so somehow "shadows" the outer `$index`.

One solution would be to access the parent $index using the following notation:

```
{{$parent.$index}}
```

Generally referencing a parent scope's data is bad practice, especially when you define several nested controllers. In this case, I think it is okay. Probably there is also another way to redefine the variable used for the index...

Comment: {{$parent.$index}} would give the result of outerloop. I need to access the innerloop respectively  [[0,1],[0,1]]

Comment: Okay, I see. By using `items in DataAPI` you are creating a scoped variable called `items` which hides the `items` variable of your controller scope. Just rename it to something else... But be aware what you want to loop over. Is the size of the DataAPI result the same as your items array? What do you want to achieve here? Looks like this requirement should better be handled inside the controller where you have better control.

Comment: $scope.DataAPI is a product of.   function chunk(arr, size) { var newArr = []; for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) { newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size)); } return newArr; } $scope.DataApi = chunk($scope.items, 2); how can to I access the innerloop respectively [[0,1],[0,1]] $index is only reading the first subarray

Answer (score 0):

here i am not sure what you are trying to do.

in view you are using `ng-repeat="items in DataAPI"` but you already have `$scope.items` in controller.so in inner loop you cant access controllers `$scope.items` because inner loop already has `items` from outer `ng-repeat`.

so make sure what you want in inner loop.you want items from controller scope or items from outer loop scope?

Comment: $scope.DataAPI is a product of function chunk(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
  }
  return newArr;
}
$scope.chunkedData = chunk(myData, 2);

Comment: how can to I access the innerloop respectively [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]] $index is only reading the first subarray [0,1]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the freedom to modify the `$scope.DataAPI`, then try modifying it in a json format, as illustrated below:

```
$scope.DataAPI = [{"name": "orange"}, {"name": "mango"}, {"name": "grape"}, {"name": "apple"}, {"name": "pineapple"}, {"name": "lemon"}];
```

Then access the data accordingly.

Comment: i have updated my code http://codepen.io/netwrkx/pen/VamRjo $scope.DataAPI is a product of                                                     function chunk(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=size) {
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
  }
  return newArr;
}

$scope.DataAPI = chunk($scope.items, 2);                                                            i want to access each object respectively